# WP7 - Databind ListboxItem's IsEnabled Property

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I have a Listbox with its ItemsSource property databound to a collection of objects. Each of the objects in the collection have an `Enabled` property which I would like to bind to their respective ListboxItem. I tried this approach:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

This results in AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_UNKNOWN_ERROR failing on this line:

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}" />
```

How do I bind to the IsEnabled property on ListboxItems (using Windows Phone 7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding within property setters is a [Silverlight 5](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/05/binding-on-style-setter-in-silverlight.html) feature. Windows Phone 7 uses Silverlight 3, so this feature is not available. Windows Phone 7.1 uses Silverlight 4, so this feature is not even part of Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango). You have a long wait on your hands!

There are some workarounds out there. See the blog post *[As the platform evolves, so do the workarounds (Better SetterValueBindingHelper makes Silverlight Setters better-er!)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx)*.

You could also subclass `ListBox`, overriding `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` to add your binding as each `ListBoxItem` is added. See an example in *[A Fast Loading Windows Phone 7 NavigationList Control](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/04/a-fast-loading-windows-phone-7-navigationlist-control/)* for using that override.

Comment: Perfect, I ended up subclassing ListBox. Thank you so much.