# Binding ListBoxItem's IsEnabled property with ItemTemplate set

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I have the following ListBox:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         SelectionChanged="ListBoxContainerSelectionChanged"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderListBoxItemStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Controls:MoviesItemControl Header="{Binding Title}"
                                        Detail="{Binding FormattedDescription}"
                                        Rating="{Binding Rating}"
                                        Opacity="{Binding IsSuppressed, Converter={StaticResource DimIfTrueConverter}}" 
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsSuppressed, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'm trying to set the Disabled state of `ListBoxItem`s that are 'Suppressed' (Movies with no description found). I have a property which I am able to bind to my individual control, but I want them to not be selectable in the actual list. (And use the disabled state included in my `ItemsContainerStyle`)

I have seen a few implementations on SO using `Trigger`, but that does not seem to be available in WP7, and I would prefer to not have to create a different style for each control  so that they bind properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following question: [WP7 - Databind ListboxItem's IsEnabled Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261573/wp7-databind-listboxitems-isenabled-property)

Which in turn links to this: [Better SetterValueBindingHelper makes Silverlight Setters better-er!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx)

I tried out `SetterValueBindingHelper` by [David Anson](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/david%20anson/) for this specific scenario and it worked great. All you have to do is to add *SetterValueBindingHelper.cs* to your project and then you can bind `IsEnabled` in the setter like this

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="delay:SetterValueBindingHelper.PropertyBinding">
        <Setter.Value>
            <delay:SetterValueBindingHelper Property="IsEnabled"
                                            Binding="{Binding IsSuppressed}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a new `Style` specifically for this list since not all my `models `have this `IsSuppressed` flag, but I want the same interaction. Is there a way to achieve this using just 1 `Style` without adding that property to each `model`?